# Java UnknownFormatConversionException : Conversion = 'm'

Tags: java, format, type-conversion

i have code like this

```
if (jcb_rtsplit.isSelected()) {
        ArrayList<String> temp = P.RT_Split(dataTraining);
        writeFile(temp);
        cekRTSplit = true;
        cekRT = true;
    }
```

and code method writefile() like this:

```
public void writeFile(ArrayList<String> temp){
    CreatingFile file = new CreatingFile();
    file.openFile("RT Split.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        file.addRecord(temp.get(i));
    }
    file.close();
}
```

and this is code CreatingFile like this :

```
private Formatter x;
public void openFile(String name){
    try {
        x = new Formatter(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("you have an error");
    }
}

public void addRecord(String input){
    x.format(input);
    x.format("%n", "pratiwi");
}

public void close(){
    x.close();

}
```

but when i run this program , i have error like this :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'm'
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2691)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2720)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at program.CreatingFile.addRecord(CreatingFile.java:25)
at program.TUtama.writeFile(TUtama.java:758)
```

anyone can help my code ? Thank's

Comment: where is the related code? program.CreatingFile.addRecord

Comment: @Jens 
The code above I have edited

Comment: And the Content of the parameter name is?

Comment: @Jens example : "datatraining.txt" . that is the content of parameter name

Comment: And the Content of Input is?

Comment: @Jens this is content of the input -> [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nb3nby8uuw35pnd/a.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file contains a "%m" which causes the exception ("52.01% mengungguli "). You can try it with this simple example:

```
    Formatter f = new Formatter("datatraining.txt");
    f.format("%m");
    f.format("%n", "pratiwi");
    f.close();
```

OUTPUT:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'm'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

You have to make sure that the % sign is escaped if it is not a Format specifier

Comment: i just added ' System.out.println(f.format("%m"));' ??

Comment: @FaniaIndah sorry Did not get you